# Copying text from one field to another if check box is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to send text from one text box to another, if a checkbox is checked. The fields were created in two different XAML files.

The first XAML file (InvolvedPersonStackPanel) contains the check box and the text box:

[image]

If this check box is checked, the text from the involved person text box should be copied to another text box created in a different XAML file, seen below:

[image]

In the InvolvedPersonStackPanel.xaml.cs file i have written this code:

```
void LivesWithCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    per.LivesWithTextBox.Text = personTextBox.Text;
}
```

This is not working for me, but i am not sure of the issue. Maybe I should try this in the other xaml.cs file..

Comment: What would happen if someone changes the Involved Person after checking the CheckBox. Should they be in sync? Should it be possible to change the LivesWithTextBox text without changing the InvolvedPerson one?

Comment: Yes as long as that check box is checked they should be in sync.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using a ViewModel to bind between two Views like this though. Read up on the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern for more information.

Basically, each of your XAML files will be a `View`. You should then ensure that they share the same instance of a `ViewModel` as their DataContext. If this is done, you can use the `ViewModel` below:

I strongly urge anyone wanting to work with WPF to learn the MVVM sooner rather than later.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _involvedPerson;
    private string _livesWithPerson;
    private bool _livesWith;

    public string InvolvedPerson
    {
        get { return _involvedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _involvedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InvolvedPerson");
        }
    }

    public string LivesWithPerson
    {
        get
        {
            if (LivesWith)
            {
                return InvolvedPerson;
            }
            return _livesWithPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            if (LivesWith)
            {
                InvolvedPerson = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _livesWithPerson = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("LivesWithPerson");
        }
    }
    public bool LivesWith
    {
        get { return _livesWith; }
        set
        {
            _livesWith = value;
            if (_livesWith)
            {
                LivesWithPerson = null;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("LivesWith");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Please not that it is also possible to have your checked event change the binding on the LivesWith TextBox to point to the InvolvedPerson property instead. But personally, I prefer having logic like this in a ViewModel, where it is easily tested by unit tests.

Comment: Help me out.  That looks like exactly what the OP has posted to me.

Comment: And just to avoid confusing anyone else. I have now also edited my answer based on OPs response to my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Heres my answer sir, your logic is right but you need this :
>
> C# WPF

design:

2 textbox
1 checkbox

> //Your previous answer
>
> ```
>     private void YourCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         txtOutput.Text = txtInput.Text;
>     }
> ```
>
> // ----------You missing this one!!!! you need to add this
>
> ```
>     private void txtInput.Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (YourCheckBox.IsChecked == true) { txtOutput.Text = txtInput.Text; }
>     }
> ```
>
> // finally here it will looks like :
>
> ```
>     private void YourCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>     {
>         txtOutput.Text = txtInput.Text;
>     }
>
>     private void txtInput.Text_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
>     {
>
>         if (YourCheckBox.IsChecked == true) { txtOutput.Text = txtInput.Text; }
>     }
> ```
>
> // I hope it works :D

Comment: This does work on two fields from the same form, but not working when transferring input from one form to another..